# How to read source path from pdb

Tags: c#, .net, pdb-files

How can you read the source paths used to compile a pdb in .NET (C#) environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PDB format is NOT documented - but there is an API from MS called DIA which provides several methods to deal PDB. It is COM-based... for details see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx). PDB files usually contain filenames and linenumbers BUT I am not sure that they always contains full path to the source.

Some interesting information on PDBs can be found [here](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx).

IF you want some .NET source code dealing with .PDBs see [`Mono.Cecil`](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) and esp. the namespace `Mono.Cecil.Pdb` .

**2/12/16 update**

Microsoft has been open-sourcing the PDB format. Information can be found in their github repo [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb).