# Is there a way to find exe compilation path

Tags: c#

In .Net,Is there a way to find the  path where an exe or dll is compiled? Is there any tool or a method to find it? I have the exe and dlls, is there a way to back track from the exe or dll

Comment: are you using an IDE?

Comment: Do you mean if I compiled the dll on my computer, and you ran it on your computer, you would want it to report the path on my computer where it was compiled?

Comment: Because if you're wanting the situation hatchet describes, that would be a horrible security problem if it were possible.

Comment: I deployed this application in the server long back and i lost track of the latest code. So to track the latest code i was trying to find the path where it was compiled. I hope this makes sense now..

Answer (score 4):

If you have the .pdb file, it will contain the path that it was compiled in. I have no idea how to read it though. Maybe this will get you started (if it's an option for you): [How to read source path from pdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585192/how-to-read-source-path-from-pdb)

Comment: You can also do this using the PE32 debug section. The debug section has the location of the output pdb file. I can put together an example of grabbing it.